# Insert string into SQL query without quotes

Tags: c#

I need to make a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Row.DATA = value
```

Where `DATA` I need to pass through `SqlParameter`. If I do something like this:

```
string value = "DATA";
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Row.@Val = value");
sql.Parameters.Add("@Val", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value;
```

I get following query which is invalid:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Row.'DATA' = value
```

Comment: The Parameter is supposed to be your value, not data

Comment: `SqlParameters` used to provide values, they're not intended to pass table names, schemas or other things than potentially assigned values.

Comment: Additionally, try `PREPARE stmt1 FROM "yourqueryhere"` then `EXECUTE stmt1 USING @Val` to execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = "DATA";
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Row.{value} = value");
```

Comment: I know that this is one simple solution. But isn't it insecure?

Comment: This will work only if the OP is *extremely* careful and *only* uses known strings for `value`.

Comment: @VladGavrilov I think it's security because injection come from the value (in the right), with a strange value for the column , the query will fail